# Is it feasible to do coding with dart on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, dart, flutter

Is it feasible to do coding with dart on Xcode? If yes then please let us know how to do the same.
Also is there any way to use flutter with the help of Xcode as an ide?

Comment: I don't think there is any Dart support for XCode. Most use AndroidStudio or VSCode which have both great support (or IntelliJ). I think there is also some support for vim and Emacs (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

To use dart you need to use Android Studio, Visual Studio Code,IntelliJ IDEA 
these are the only supported  IDE .

there is a dart plugin for Atom,Emacs,Vim but these plugins are unsupported and available as open source.

So you cant use dart with xCode for the moment .